# How to get pageurl form which error is occurred in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

How to get pageurl from which error is occurred in asp.net.
i just need page url that is not found.
this is my code of web.config for custom error

```
<customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx?handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx?msg=404&amp;handler=customErrors%20section%20-%20Web.config"/>
 </customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an HttpModule to catch all the errors and do a lot more than find the url that caused the 404. You can also catch 500 errors and do whatever you want to do with it.

```
public class ErrorModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += context_Error;
    }

    void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var error = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
        if (error.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            //use web.config to find where we need to redirect
            var config = (CustomErrorsSection) WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/customErrors");

            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;

            string requestedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            string urlToRedirectTo = config.Errors["404"].Redirect;
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(urlToRedirectTo + "&errorPath=" + requestedUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to register it in the httpModules section of the web.config file:

```
<httpmodules>
    …
    <add name="ErrorModule" type="ErrorModule, App_Code"/>
</httpmodules>
```

And in your `ErrorPage.aspx` you can get the url from the query string:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = Request["errorPath"];
}
```